# Nest.js express-session Set-Cookie header is not working - CORS issue

Tags: nestjs, express-session, setcookie

I've got the frontend and backend on different servers. when I first deployed the services I've got "SameSite: none" because of different origins, then when I set it to none, it required me to set "Secure: true" as well, after setting that I'm unable to see the Set-cookie header on server's response and on production the cookie is just not recieved.

here's main.ts with the express-session middleware:

```js
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule);
  const sessionSecret = app.get(AppConfigService).getConfig().session.secret;
  const frontDomain = app.get(AppConfigService).getConfig().front.domain;
  const port = app.get(AppConfigService).getConfig().app.port;

  app.setGlobalPrefix('api');

  app.use(
    session({
      name: 's.id',
      secret: sessionSecret,
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      cookie: {
        maxAge: 360000, // 1hour in seconds
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? false : true,
      },
      store: new PrismaSessionStore(new PrismaClient(), {
        checkPeriod: 2 * 60 * 1000, //ms
        dbRecordIdIsSessionId: true,
        dbRecordIdFunction: undefined,
      }),
    }),
  );
  app.enableCors({
    origin: [frontDomain, `${frontDomain}/`],
    credentials: true,
  });
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
  await app.listen(port);
}
bootstrap();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, it works for me

```
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule{cors: true,});
```

Comment: I'm trying it right now, thanks, i'll update!

Comment: This did not change anything sadly, here is the frontend: https://sikum-net.xarielah.dev it's in Hebrew (I believe google translate tranlsates it automatically) so you can try to login: testuser password: 12345 to check the request